# Can SQL Agent job notifications be sent to one operator for success and another for failure?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

We have a requirement that some people are sent notification on success, and other on failure.

[image]

But the UI seems to only allow a combination of 1 operator + 1 condition.

So I was wondering if we could do perhaps by transact sql in the MSDB?

Answer (score 8):

Quite frankly, I would just not use the limited operators facility through the UI and instead:

- Create a step that only gets reached when the job succeeds, which e-mails person 1
- Create another step that only gets reached when any step fails, which e-mails person 2

(You may need to modify multiple steps that could potentially fail, such that when they do fail, processing moves immediately to the second step above.)

You can still use operators if you like, just have the steps manually call [`sp_notify_operator`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188349.aspx).

Comment: This was going to be my fall back solution. Thanks for the vote of confidence!

Comment: @Preet yeah, I've had to do some pretty convoluted and cumbersome things to work around Agent limitations, and it hasn't really seen much love at all in many versions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for mentioning `sp_notify_operator`, I hadn't seen that one before (always queried `sysoperators` and used `sp_send_dbmail`). The custom steps are also a great way to go ahead and send the details of the errors from the logs instead of relying on the default "the job failed" emails.  I normally go ahead and configure on the e-mail failure notification for the job, in addition to having the manual email step, in case the manual notification step fails. Then you can use that same failure operator from `msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view.notify_email_operator_id` in your manual step.

Comment: SQL Agent seems to be the black sheep in the family I hope one day they will fully integrate it with the availability group feature.

Answer (score 2):

So this is what I came up with as a workaround if the intention is that multiple people in your organization should be notified if a job fails and a different group of multiple people for successes.

You will notice the Steps 1-3 are the normal tasks that the schedule job is uses for as you would do for your task. There can as many steps as needed before these but the last step (Step 3) of the process need to break “On Success” and “On Failure” to go into separate emails. Also all “On Failures” need to continue to your “Failure Email” as highlighted below. So the Failure group gets there emails and the job will still fail for the historical records.

[image: 1.1]

You will see the option to change the direction of the “On success action” and “On Failure action” in the Advanced tab of the Job steps.

[image: 2]

Failure Email Step -General Property

[image: 3]

Failure Email Step -Advance Property

[image: 4]

Success Email Step -General Property

[image: 5]

Success Email Step -Advance Property

[image: 6]

For others in need of help [Notify multiple operators with difference results](https://sqlhiker.com/2016/07/09/notify-multiple-operators-with-difference-results/)

Comment: Sorry gentles didn't know I couldn't. I have corrected the post. Hope this is better?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, using the UI.

Select alerts and create one alert for the failure and one for the success conditions
Then, select notifications and  and tick email and on the combo, select when Job completes.

Note: Job will complete Either with success or failure. However the alert, will determine what message to send out.

Enjoy!

Comment: claudio, could you please specify this oppertunity a bit? where can I create an alert for failure/success? TY